# How to get attribute of a django model's foreign key object using getattr in python?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have two models as such

```
class first(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    y = models.ForeignKey(second)

class second(models.Model):
    random = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now if I want value of `name` for a `first` object instance using `getattr`, I can do `getattr(x, 'name')` where `x` is a `first` object but if I try the same with `getattr(x, 'y.random')` , it throws me an error even though `x.y.random` is a totally valid query.

Is it possible to query `x.y.random` if all I have is object `x` and string 'y.random'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it tries to fetch property `'y.random'`, though there is no such property, and it's not even valid to have a property with `.`.

```
getattr(getattr(x, 'y'), 'random'))
```

Comment: Yes now I feel so stupid, I can just do a check for if the string contains '.' and if it does, split it up and do exactly what you said.